# Is it harmful to write to a GPIO pin when there is nothing hooked up?

Tags: gpio, electronics

Is it possible to harm the Raspberry Pi by writing to a GPIO pin through software when there is nothing hooked up? From what I understand, this should not do any damage, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Perfectly safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understand correctly - there is no problem at all

Comment: To expand on what John said if you have nothing connected no current can flow no matter how the pin is configured. think of it like an extension cord with nothing connected to it.